# Homepage disappeared from firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google

The usual modified Google homepage for Mozilla Firefox has disappeared.

Now, when I start browser it says `browser.startup.homepage=about:home` and the address link is `chrome://branding/locale/browserconfig.properties`.

How to bring my modified Google homepage back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**about:startpage is the default.**

In Firefox, go to edit then preferences, set the home page to **about:startpage**. Hope this works!

Comment: +1 :D. You can also set it to: `http://start.ubuntu.com/14.04/Google/?sourceid=hp` - `about:startpage` must of been what the OP meant by 'modified google homepage'...

Comment: Yeah, probably, and your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can very simply change it in the preferences:
                        [image: Screenshot]
You can add in your home page URL next to *'Home Page:'*, and set what you want it to show on start with the option next to *'When Firefox starts:'*